# How to handle bot with no permissions error discord

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have a bot and it has a few commands where the bot needs ban perms and manage channel perms etc. How would I make the bot say "I don't have the permission to do that" when a user tries to make a command the bot cant do. For example a ban command but the bot doesn't have ban perms. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
   await ctx.send("I dont have the permission to do that!")
   return
```

but it doesn't work. The error is:

```
Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

How would i go on about making the bot say it doesn't have permissions if a user tries executing a command the bot cant do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.Forbidden` is not an error you that you typically handle in the error handler, you have to use a try/except block in the command itself

```py
async def foo(ctx):
    try:
        ...
    except discord.Forbidden:
        return await ctx.send("I dont have the permission to do that!")
```

However it is possible to handle it in the error handler

```
# If an error happens inside the command,
# discord.py wraps it around with `commands.CommandInvokeError` 
# which has the `original` attribute which is the "original" error
error = getattr(error, "original", error) 
if isinstance(error, discord.Forbidden):
    return await ctx.send("I dont have the permission to do that!")
```